# How to check if there are no char before the string?

Tags: c

Lets say I have char *string. Now I want to make sure there is nothing before 't'. How would I check that? This is my approach but it doesn't seem to work.

```
char * str = "test";
checker(str);
------------------------------------------------
int checker(char * string){
    char *idx = string;
    idx--;
    if(*idx != '\0'){ //there should be no char before t
        return 1; 
    }
```

I have tried '\n' and '\0'.

Comment: Do you mean that the first character must be 't' or can there be spaces before 't'?

Comment: Are you trying to check whether a `char *` you've got points into the middle of a string instead of the beginning?  There's no reliable way to do that without other information to check with.

Comment: There are two `'t'`s in `"test"`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to check whether or not  a pointer passed to a function points to the first element. If you decrement the pointer to a location *before* the region of storage allocated to the pointer, you invoke *undefined behaviour*.

The decremented pointer might end up pointing to a completely different variable than the one passed to your function or some uninitialized memory with unpredictable results. The pointer may even point outside the memory allocated to your process resulting in a crash.

Undefined behaviour may even result in your program working as expected for years until it starts failing in mysterious ways, sometimes in completely unrelated parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

As you said there should be no characters before `t`, **in the `checker()` function just check if the first element of your sent string is `t` or not.**

```
int checker(char* string)
{
    if(string[0]=='t')
       return 1;
    return 0;
}
```